# Netty how to use ByteToMessageCodec?

Tags: java, netty

My intention was to create a codec subclass for every message I have. For example, I have a handshake message, so I would have a codec for said handshake message. I have another concrete message, acompanied with its own concrete codec.

The message's header starts with an opcode, and I am wondering, how will Netty know what codec to use to decode the byte buffer if I don't tell it how to determine that?

I thought of a few ways but none seem to make sense. Do I need to maybe make some kind of intermediate crude message that contains the parsed header and unparsed body?

But then the question remains, how do I select what codec to use to decode the body? Do I do this manually (for example with an array of my codec instances, which doesn't make sense to me) that I would then access like `codecs[opcode]`, or does Netty have something to make this selection for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual pattern would  be to have an opcode decoding handler in the pipeline. Once the decoder reads the op code and determines which message handler the opcode maps to, it adds the mapped message handler to the pipeline and removes itself. On completion (or failure) the opcode decoding handler would be added back into the pipeline and the prior message handler removed.

Comment: Can I keep using the same instances of the handlers when adding them back to the pipeline? There will be a lot of messages processed, I don't know if it's wise to instantiate the new stuff every time a message is received. Perhaps it's even wiser to just have one big handler for all the types of messages in some kind of switch/if-list. Or have the decoding/encoding happen in each of the message classes. I don't know the preferred pattern to use from Netty :(

Comment: You can use the same handler instances, provided they're sharable (i.e. they keep no state). They will also need to be annotated with @ChannelHandler.Sharable to certify so.

Comment: I've been testing this out, but I don't like that I should remove/replace/add handlers on the pipeline with every message. I've decided that I will just have a codec for the header, then a handler to determine what message class the opcode maps to, and then send the buffer to that instantiated message.